# Version error in the gradle files in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my gradle file. Whenever I try to compile or even do a clean build I encounter an error stating:

"Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.3.
"

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "studio.in.prakharshuka.atlastodo"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
//com.google.android.gms to 11.6.0.

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have firebase authentication and database connected to my app.

Comment: I guess your both firebase version should be 16.03

Comment: Can you show us your buildscript { dependencies { ... }} in the top level build.gradle file?

Comment: The version codes should be the same. Me too face this sometime.

Check your top-level build file for the gms-service version to match 16.0.3, I can also see your `firebase-auth` and `firebase-database` versions are also same, you can make the same for avoiding future conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be causing an error, should only have been a warning. But nevertheless try this:

1) keep both the firebase dependency at version 16.0.2.

2) add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.2'` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**First Step**

- if you are using google-services dependency all the version are same like this:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
  applicationId "studio.in.prakharshuka.atlastodo"
  minSdkVersion 22
  targetSdkVersion 28
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
  testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
  buildTypes {
  release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
    }
     }
       //com.google.android.gms to 11.6.0.

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }


   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  ```

**Second step**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}


  allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
 }


task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```